# Intellij Text Replacement settings

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, keyboard-shortcuts

As title says, is there any that replace a shortcut to an phrase.
Example
Shortcut: sop
Phrase: System.out.println();

So where ever in editor I type in sop it will replace sop to my phrase. So does intellij has that feature which IOS keyboard settings have?

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ calls them Live Templates.  Go into the settings dialog and search for live templates.  It will show you those that are defined.  You can edit the existing ones and add new ones there.

Comment: _Thanks for the answer._
That's what I was looking for :)

Comment: Do I close this question or it will automatically achieve it?

Comment: I'm sort of new here but I think by accepting my answer you've closed it @RookieProgrammer